# How to handle umlaut using Python ans CGI

Tags: python, utf-8, cgi, diacritics

I have a Python-script that creates content for a webpage using CGI.
When I try to print out something with an umlaut the script stops when using CGI.
When run from the command-line it runs OK.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n\n')
print ("<!DOCTYPE html>")
print ("<html>")
print (" <head>")
print ('  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">')
print (" </head>")
print (" <body>")
print ("Mariënberg")
print (" </body>")
print ("</html>")
```

So when run in the browser it stops after the body-tag with no further message.
When run from the command-line: no problem.
If I replace the e-umlaut by a normal e: no problem with CGI and webpage shows Marienberg.

Do I miss something obvious?

Thanks in advance,
Derko

Comment: Try using HTML entity `&euml;` instead of `ë`

Comment: Are you on Windows? You use `print` which in windows do not print UTF-8 strings. But you say in HTML that you are using UTF-8, so browser may find corrupted data

Comment: I get data from an API and besides e-umlaut there are dozen of other 'strange'  characters.

Comment: No, I am on Linux.

Comment: `print ("Mariënberg".encode( 'ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace').decode( 'ascii'))` could do the trick…

Comment: * look at the script file encoding. You're using literal text, and if you're not encoding the file in UTF-8, then you're not sending UTF-8
* Try not through the browser, but with `curl -Lsi http://addr` and see what you get exactly. Maybe redirect it to a file by adding `> some_file.txt` at the end, and see if that file can be safely read with UTF-8.
* Don't you need to declare content-length?